Film about a man tied to a chair by his captor, a woman in a red latex dress
When I was fairly young I saw a movie scene which has been etched on my mind for a while. I've always wanted to see the rest of the movie to get some sense of the context of it.
In the scene I saw a man is tied to a chair by his captor: a woman in a red latex dress. The captor flips over a picture of what I think is the tied up man's wife and proceeds to rape the man. The man then had a flashback, to what I think was crime related, perhaps he was a cop or something I can't remember clearly enough. 
That's all I really remember of the scene, hopefully someone here can provide me the name so I can finally understand the story behind it all. 

Since we don't know how old you are, we don't know how long ago "I was fairly young" is. Knowing when the movie came out is important. Could you use specific info like "10 years ago" or "In 1995"? Also, any other info you have would be great. Where was the film likely made, what language was it in... etc.

You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title.

With the description you gave, here's my try: Thursday, released in 1998.

Features woman in red latex dress.
"Victim" tied up to a chair
Scene where captor flips picture and breaks it. 

